# Redirect loop error removing .php

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error, below is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,END]
RewriteRule ^([^\.\/]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is the error?  You may want to have a look at [How to Ask] for some tips on how to ask answerable questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule may not require `END` but 2nd rule will definitely require `END` flag to stop infinite redirection. You can use following rules in Apache 2.4:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [END]
```